# wordpress max upload size doesn't change

Tags: upload, localhost, max

I need to change Wordpress Maximum upload file size to something more than 2mb. 
I have changed max upload file size in Multisite Settings to 19500.
I also edited php.ini changing post_max_size to 25M, upload_max_filesize to 20M and memory_limit to 128M. 
What else do I need to do in order to achieve my goal? 
I'm on localhost on mac.

Comment: Can you please share what values you entered for multisites and php.ini

Comment: sure, i've edited the question

Comment: what of in multisites? what values are there? am asking cos multisites takes values in kilobytes(KB) so 1,500 means 1.5mb. its a common error we all make.

Comment: sorry, forgot to insert that value, but it's inserted now, too. 19500

Comment: ok. just posted an answer. lets see if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, here are a few solutions I can think of for a localhost user. With localhost, I assume you have full control so try the below options if any works let me know.

**.htaccess**
Edit the .htaccess file in your WordPress site’s root folder and add the following code:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

**Theme functions**
add the following code to the theme’s functions.php file, you can increase the upload size:

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

let me know if any of this works.

Answer (score -2):

If you don’t want coding, directly increase max upload size through this free plugin https://ziscom.today/max-upload-size/

After installation go to WordPress menu ‘Max Upload Size’
* Only enter the numeric value in bytes
* 1024 bytes = 1KB
* 1048576 bytes = 1MB

It worked for me. Hope it help for you.

Comment: You posted 3 answers in 10 minutes promoting the same templates/site. That makes these answers look like spam. Are you associated with this product in any way? If you are affiliated, you *must disclose that affiliation in the post*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).